# No value in array

Tags: php, arrays

Can't get array value `$tt`.

```
<?
$limba="ro";      
$qt=array('Total'=>'ro', 'Всего'=>'ru', 'Total'=>'en');
$tt=array_search($limba,$qt);

echo $tt;
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($tt);` to check if you getting anything. also `error_reporting(1);` to check for errors.

Comment: first of all its better to use <?php instead of <? only for php codes.

Comment: `$qt=array('Total'=>'ro', 'Всего'=>'ru', 'Total'=>'en');` You're replacing `Total = 'en'` so there are no values in the array with `ro`. The array is the same as `$qt=array('Всего'=>'ru', 'Total'=>'en');`.

Comment: @Mario the var dump is giving a false.

Comment: I don't have errors in page, but I don't have $tt variable value

Comment: Change your array to `$qt=array('Total'=>'ro', 'Всего'=>'ru');` and it will work.

Comment: Dave Chen give you an answer, rename 1 value `'Tot' => 'ro'` and check if works.

Comment: I writed second Total with russian "o"... It works !
Thanks Dave !

Comment: You should check [ask] for guidance on how to ask questions to the community here, this will also help people in the future with similar problems find solutions.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I don't knew where is the error. Now I know, that error is in array and I changed my title. Why you don't change your feedback ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have values with two identical keys.

You probably have to change first `Total` to other key, `Totalt` for example:

```
$qt=array('Totalt'=>'ro', 'Всего'=>'ru', 'Total'=>'en');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please read about [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function. It returns first corresponding key.

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

2. You should be careful playing with arrays. You must have unique key to avoid these kind of issues.

Pleas look into [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function. It might be helpful for what you are trying to achieve.

> array_keys — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

I hope this shall help.